# B and C aren't working (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm quite confused at why the option "B" or "C" doesn't work. You are supposed to be able to navigate the story by choosing any of the 3 options. The only option that works is "A". It's probably the smallest thing I have overlooked.

[Click to See the Code Window](https://repl.it/K0tG/1)

The program executes (From the Fuctions.py, SplashScreens()):

```
...
print(SplashScreen.Splash_Screen19)
cls()
Story_1_to_4(Text.Story_1,2,3,4)
```

Which runs this... (Located in Functions.py){Through = True}{Key = False}

```
def Story_1_to_4(Story_Num, Path1, Path2, Path3):
global Through
global Key
if Path1 == 3 and Path2 == 4 and Path3 == 10:
    Key = True
while Through == True:
    Choice = input(Story_Num)
    if Choice == "A":
        Choice = Path1
        Through = False
    elif Choice == "B":
        Choice = Path2
        Through == False
    elif Choice == "C":
        Choice = Path3
        Through == False
    else:
        cls()
        print(Text.Invalid_Syntax)
        time.sleep(2)
        cls()
ResetThrough()
Decision(Choice)
```

Story_1: (From Text.py)

[Image of the Variable Story_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lAYW.png)

And then Decision is... (Located in Functions.py)

```
def Decision(Choice):
cls()
if Choice == 1:
    Story_1_to_4(Text.Story_1,2,3,4)
elif Choice == 2:
    Story_1_to_4(Text.Story_2,3,4,10)
elif Choice == 3:
    Story_1_to_4(Text.Story_3,5,6,4)
elif Choice == 4:
    Story_1_to_4(Text.Story_4,7,8,9)
elif Choice == 5:
    Story_Ending(Text.Story_5)
elif Choice == 6:
    Story_Ending(Text.Story_6)
elif Choice == 7 and Key == True:
    Story_Ending(Text.Story_7_With_Key)
elif Choice == 7 and Key == False:
    Story_Ending(Text.Story_7_Without_Key)
elif Choice == 8:
    Story_Ending(Text.Story_8)
elif Choice == 9:
    Story_Ending(Text.Story_9)
elif Choice == 10:
    Story_Ending(Text.Story_10)
```

Comment: Thank you for the link to runnable code. If only all questions here could have that, it makes things much easier.

Comment: No problem @AlexHall I thought it would have been handy to help solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For A, you set `Through = False`. For B and C you wrote `Through == False` which just evaluates an expression but doesn't assign `Through`.